# Simplify $\frac{1+\sin\alpha-2\sin^2\left(45^\circ-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}{4\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}}$

Tags: trigonometry

Simplify $$\dfrac{1+\sin\alpha-2\sin^2\left(45^\circ-\dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)}{4\cos\dfrac{\alpha}{2}}$$

I am reading the solution of the authors and I really don't see how $$\dfrac{1+\sin\alpha-2\sin^2\left(45^\circ-\dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)}{4\cos\dfrac{\alpha}{2}}=\dfrac{1+\sin\alpha-(1-\cos(90^\circ-\alpha))}{4\cos\dfrac{\alpha}{2}}$$ Which identity have they used?

Comment: $\cos(2a)=1-2\sin^2(a)$

Comment: Isn't then the numerator equal to $$\cos(90^\circ-\alpha)+\sin\alpha?$$

Comment: Yes, but $\cos(90-a)=\sin(a)$

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah, Post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

We start from the classical formula

$$\cos(a+b)=$$
$$\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$$

which gives

$$\cos(2a)=\cos^2(a)-\sin^2(a)$$
$$=1-2\sin^2(a)$$

or

$$2\sin^2(a)=1-\cos(2a)$$

thus
$$2\sin^2(45-\frac{\alpha}{2})=$$
$$1-\cos(90-\alpha)=1-\sin(\alpha)$$

your expression becomes

$$\frac{1+\sin(\alpha)-(1-\sin(\alpha))}{4\cos(\frac{\alpha}{2})}=$$

$$\frac{2\sin(\alpha)}{4\cos(\frac{\alpha}{2})}=$$

$$\frac{2(2\sin(\frac{\alpha}{2})\cos(\frac{\alpha}{2}))}{4\cos(\frac{\alpha}{2})}=$$

$$\sin(\frac{\alpha}{2})$$

Answer (score 1):

Only one thing changes, namely: $2\sin(45^\circ - a/2)^2 \rightarrow 1-\cos(90^\circ - a).$

So recall the double angle formula: $\cos(2\theta) = 1 - 2\sin(\theta)^2$

Then by rearrangement $2\sin(\theta)^2 = 1 - \cos(2\theta)$.

Let $\theta = 45^\circ - a/2$, then $2\sin(45^\circ - a/2)^2 = 1-\cos(2\cdot (45^\circ - a/2)) = 1-\cos(90^\circ - a)$.